# Classifier for numeric class wekka in java

Tags: java, classification, weka, numeric, naivebayes

I am trying to write a clasifier in java using weka(3.8.1 version) but I am having trubels in finding a classier able to work. I am using NaiveByes.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ConverterUtils.DataSource source1 = new ConverterUtils.DataSource("/home/crina/workspace/lic/train.arff");
    Instances train = source1.getDataSet();
    if (train.classIndex() == -1)
        train.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() - 1);

    ConverterUtils.DataSource source2 = new ConverterUtils.DataSource("/home/crina/workspace/lic/test.arff");
    Instances test = source2.getDataSet();
    if (test.classIndex() == -1)
        test.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() - 1);

    NaiveBayes naiveBayes = new NaiveBayes();
    naiveBayes.buildClassifier(train);

    double label = naiveBayes.classifyInstance(test.instance(0));
    test.instance(0).setClassValue(label);

    System.out.println(test.instance(0));
}
```

In train.arff i have something like:

```
@relation MyRelation
@attribute id_student numeric
@attribute subject_id numeric
@attribute teacher_id numeric
@attribute level numeric
@attribute isMandatory numeric
@attribute class numeric

@data
2,1,1,5,1,80
2,3,2,5,1,100
....
```

So far I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" weka.core.UnsupportedAttributeTypeException: weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes: Cannot handle numeric class!
```

Comment: Why are "subject" and "teacher" numeric types?  That might be part of your problem.

Comment: I've edited my post. All are numeric types but Naive Bayes cannot handle numeric class.

Comment: Indeed, it cannot.  And you cannot force it to.  You should consider making these non-numeric types instead, and perhaps that will work better.

Comment: The last column must be numeric, that's why I have to find something that can handle numeric class.

Comment: You may want to consider a regression algorithm then, given that your problem is not one of classification.